# Can't specify size in glTexSubImage2D

Tags: c, opengl, texture-mapping

I am trying to create a subtexture over a texture that has been applied to 2D quad. It is working correctly when default parameters (width and heigth) are passed but when I enter integral size such as 100 for width and 100 for height output is not correct. Scan lines are shown in the desried region. Here is the code

```
unsigned char* grass_image = SOIL_load_image("grass1.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, grass_image);

SOIL_free_image_data(grass_image);

unsigned char* temple_image = SOIL_load_image("temple.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height,
    GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, temple_image); // NO ERROR

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100,
    GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, temple_image); // ERROR

SOIL_free_image_data(temple_image);
```

Comment: Well, interpreting image data with a different size than it's real size is going to cause it to look weird. Additionally, [have you set the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` setting to match the data you are using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046619/glgetteximage-reads-too-much-data-with-texture-format-gl-alpha/26048033#26048033)?

Comment: That should not be a problem if I am mapping it to smaller size than its original size. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: OpenGL uses the width parameter to determine how long a row is. If you specify a width of less than the image's actual width, then the scanlines don't match up and you'll have a weird image.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to set the stride, right now the second row of pixels in the SubImage will be pixel 101-200 of the first row of pixels in the original image.

You need to set the stride using `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, stride);` like so:

```
unsigned char* temple_image = SOIL_load_image("temple.jpg", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100,
    GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, temple_image);
```

Comment: After adding that line just a part of image is showing up. If the image is 400X400 and I have passed 100 as width and height value then only top left quarter is showing up. Whereas I want entire 400X400 image to be mapped into 100X100. Is there a way for that??

Comment: @MohitJain You'd have to resize it yourself.

Comment: As colonel said, you have to resize it yourself, OpenGL doesn't do that for you.