# glTexSubImage2D access violation

Tags: opengl, devil

```
class classOne
{
    ILuint id;

    unsigned char* data()
    {
        ilBindImage(id); 
        return ilGetData();
    }
}

class classTwo
{
    void method(classOne& some)
    {
        (...)
        glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 8, GL_RGB8, w, h);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, w, h, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, some.data());
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}
```

I get an "access violation" error when my program comes to glTexSubImage2D. What am i doing wrong?

i've set GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT to 1. Though if I try this

```
auto pdata = new unsigned char[some.dataSize()]; 
memcpy(data,some.data(),some.dataSize())
```

and then pass pdata to glTexSubImage2D - everything seems to be okay...

Comment: Are you sure that `some.data()` is long enough?

Comment: Also make sure that [the `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` setting is configured correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046619/glgetteximage-reads-too-much-data-with-texture-format-gl-alpha/26048033#26048033) for the data you're using.

Comment: How does some.dataSize() figure out the size of the buffer?

Comment: @kolrabi GLuint getDataize()const
 {
  return ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_SIZE_OF_DATA);
 }

Answer (score 0):

It seems i've set incorrect image format - GL_RGBA8/GL_BGRA, while it must be GL_RGB8/GL_BGR as in my code sample. I've tricked myself.